# JQuery fadeIn/fadeOut on hover from the left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a fadeIn and fadeOut effect when hovering but it doesn't seem to work!

```
<div class="icon_menu">
    <div class="text_menu_slide">Logout</div> x
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".icon_menu").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeIn();
    },function(){
        $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeOut();
    });        
});
```

css:

```
.text_menu_slide{
    display:none;
}
.icon_menu:hover .text_menu_slide, .icon_menu{
    display:inline;     
}
```

DEMO:
**http://jsfiddle.net/XwnGA/**

Comment: in your fiddle you don't reference the jquery lib

Comment: also the css `display: inline` will probably override the fadein/out effect

Comment: oh my bad. here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwnGA/3/ but it is been weird still

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/XwnGA/5/

Comment: i didn't want the width like that. the solution was to put float:left for both and it worked!

Comment: I guess, using a div where span is required seems bit weird for me. You are using a float and making it work like span there again. Instead why dont you go straight for span tag.

Comment: Well, why dont you accept one of the answers below, which you thought has helped you achieve your goal. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display:inline css code is not required. At the frameworks and extensions where **No Library** is displayed select any of jQuery versions. Moreover you can use a span tag instead of div.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="icon_menu">
    <span class="text_menu_slide">Logout</span> x
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.text_menu_slide{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery CODE**

```
$(function(){
    $(".icon_menu").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeIn();
    },function(){
        $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeOut();
    });        
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XwnGA/4/)

Comment: that still makes it go on top if the width isn't 100%

Comment: how can i restrict it to only react to the x hover and not the entire width of the page next to the x?

Comment: @Gadgetster the problem is you've used a div as the icon menu container. You need to make this inline or use a different element eg `<a class="icon_menu"></a>` or wrap the **X** with hyperlink and make that the hover target

Answer (score 2):

There are **3 Issue** in your code

**Issue 1** : Include  jQuery lib

**Issue 2** : Remove `Display: inline` from Below Code

```
.icon_menu:hover .text_menu_slide, .icon_menu{
  /* display:inline*/   /*Remove this as this overwrite JS fadeIn */
}
```

**Issue 3**  Not actually a issue but for the behavior you want make the `div` `.text_menu_slide` to `span`

**NOTE** You can also move the `X` before `span` ti avoid the shifting

See the **[LAB DEMO](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/~YZKAQzOAZT!1WmocLMgmKQQCq!jX!Kt)**

**Edit:2**

The `.icon_menu` is Block level element use Below css for making it inline Or you can always use **inline elements (such as span)**

```
.icon_menu{
  display:inline; 
}
```

Comment: the shifting is fine, it will actually be on the right side of the screen on my website. how do i make it only react to the hover on the x rather than the whole width of that line?

Comment: use .icon_menu{    display:inline; }  in CSS

Comment: Updated my lab Demo Please check if its fine http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/~YZKAQzOAZT!1WmocLMgmKQQCq!jX!Kt

Comment: beauty! last thing, i notice that the 'logout' blinks if i don't move the mouse away. is there a way to stop it blinking like that? it seems like if the mouse is within the div but outside the text then it blinks

Comment: add `.stop(true,true)` before fadeIn/fadeOut. Updated my demo Please check

Comment: @Gadgetster Although Answer has been accepted by you what you need more? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwnGA/2/)

you didnt included the jquery file in it.

```
$(function(){
$(".icon_menu").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeOut( "slow");
});        
});
$(function(){
$(".icon_menu").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeIn( "slow");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing

Your fiddle didn't had jQuery.

Second,

You have .icon_menu:hover in your css. This is hindering the effect. Remove this line and it works.

Here is the new css

```
.text_menu_slide{
display:none;
}
.icon_menu .text_menu_slide, .icon_menu{
   display:inline;  
}
```

Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2yu52/

[EDIT]
As per the comment, you want to start from hidden

Change div to span and then have this css.

```
.text_menu_slide{
 display:none;
}
```

Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2yu52/1/

Comment: i want it to start from hidden!

Comment: I dont thing the repetition is necessary here (in CSS). ;)

Comment: how do you make it only react to the hover on the x?

Comment: Although you can do that, but it would not be a very good thing to do. When logout will fadeIn then again hoverOut of your x will be called, which will cause it to be in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $(".icon_menu").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeOut( "slow");
   });        
});
$(".icon_menu").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").fadeIn( "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon_menu">
    <span class="text_menu_slide">Logout</span> x
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text_menu_slide{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

Dont forget to clear queue with stop() to avoid animation repeat.

```
$(function(){
    $(".icon_menu").hover(function(){

        $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    },function(){

        $(this).find(".text_menu_slide").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });        
});
```

Comment: i was just thinking of that! it blinked before. this helps somewhat if the mouse isn't moving around too much

Comment: to avoid blinking you can debounce your animation function - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ - it can help you to call animation function with necessary interval

Answer (score 0):

Slightly rewritten.

http://jsfiddle.net/XwnGA/22/

### HTML

```
<div class="icon_menu">
    <div class="text_menu_slide">Logout</div> x
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(".icon_menu").mouseover(function() {$(".text_menu_slide").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 300)});
$(".icon_menu").mouseleave(function() {$(".text_menu_slide").stop().animate({opacity:0}, 500)});
```

### CSS

```
.icon_menu * {display: inline;}
.text_menu_slide {opacity: 0;}
```